# How to add certificate on okhttp

Tags: java, spring, rest, ssl

I am building an application in Spring. The application is supposed to make some REST calls to Starling's sandbox/developer exposed API.

I am trying to make a call to Starlings api but since it's under HTTPS, i get the following:

```
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Upon reading Starlings documentation, it does provide the certificate I need along with the following instructions:

> You will need to embed the certificate during development and
> associate it with our domain. Then, during the SSL challenge with us
> your application should validate our identity with the certificates.
> Libraries to do this are available for almost all languages and
> platforms, for example TrustKit on iOS and okhttp for Java.

I am using okhttp to make the calls but I can't figure out how to make okhttp accept the certificate. I did come across this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40389150/how-to-enable-certificate-pinning-with-okhttp) and tried to implement it but wasn't sure what to put for the value of the hostname. In the answer it has:
`.add(hostname, "sha256/AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")`... is the the sha56/AAAAA supposed to be the contents of the certificate?

EDIT: I have tried placing the contents of the certificate within the "sha56/AAA" area and got the following:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: pins must start with 'sha256/' or 'sha1/': MIIGQDCCBSigAwIBAgIMA/4EOE5OkRQN7SNQMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMFAxCzAJ

so I'm guessing I'll need to somehow generate the the sha using the cert?

Comment: This link could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25509296/trusting-all-certificates-with-okhttp

Comment: Still same issue. I have even followed their example on GitHub: https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java but still same issue occuring